# jquery floating div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

**What I have?**

1. A html-table which has a lot of rows.
2. A hidden (display=none) div which contains some input controls (lets call it "div-to-display"). Only one div-to-display in whole page.

**What I'm trying to do?**

When the mouse hovers on the first cell in each row - show the "div-to-display" below it (like tool tip).

**But**, I can't create a separated div-to-display div for each table row. All cells must use the same "div-to-display" element.

While showing the div-to-display div, it should be float. What it means is that it won't change the location of the other cells in the table. It will be above them.

Do you have idea how to do this with `jquery``javascript`?

Comment: Please show some code what you have tried ?

Comment: can you post little of **what you have** and **what you'r trying to do**

Comment: It's so abstract... add code or you won't get answers.

Comment: look into jquery `offset()`

Comment: I think this is when absolute positioning can be used and then you can use either `position()` or `offset()` jQuery method to return position values of element in JSON format for required manipulation and setting. You can read more in the documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/sBtxq/

### JQuery

```
// Add our div to every td
$('td').append('<div class="div-to-display">yay</div>');
```

### CSS

```
.div-to-display {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: 10;
}
td {
    position: relative;
}
td:hover > .div-to-display {
    display: block
}
```

---

### Updated (non-JS) version

### CSS

```
td {
    position: relative;
}
td:after {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: 10;
    content: "yay";
}
td:hover:after {
    display: block
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sBtxq/20/**

Comment: thanks a million for this non js version! just what I needed!

Comment: This is just what I have been looking for a long time. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

use jquery [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method to get position of hover of those elements and apply that as a left and top for the div. (Make sure to position the div as ABSOLUTE).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple solution try using tooltip plugins. There will be loads available out there. One such is jquery UI [tooltip plugin](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

Answer (score 0):

Style it on your own

```
#div-to-display{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:50px;
width:300px;
height:200px;
z-index:99999;
display:none;
}
```

add this `class="toHover"` to each or table rows whom on hover you want to show div

add  this function

```
  window.onload = function(){

    $('.toHover').each(function() {

         $(this).mouseenter(function(){ $('#div-to-display').show(); });
         $(this).mouseleave(function() { $('#div-to-display').hide();});
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html For i.e.

```
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="divInput" style="display:none;position:absolute;">
        <input type="type" name="name" value=" " />
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = 'ss';
    $('table tr').each(function () {
        var this_tr = $(this);
        this_tr.find('td:first').mouseenter(function () {
            var this_td = $(this);

            $('#divInput').css({ top: this_td.offset().top + this_td.height(), left: this_td.offset().left });
            $('#divInput').show();
        }).mouseout(function () {
            var this_td = $(this);
            $('#divInput').css({ top: this_td.offset().top + this_td.height(), left: this_td.offset().left });
            $('#divInput').hide();
        })
    })
</script>
```